# How will a wait command in a script be affected if wait is disabled on the server

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a few scripts which use the wait command, for example this rocketjumping script:

```
alias +rocketjump "+jump; +duck; wait; +attack"
alias -rocketjump "-jump; -attack; wait; wait; wait; -duck"
bind "MOUSE2" "+rocketjump"
```

So what will happen if this script gets executed on a 'wait-disabled' server? Will the wait command be skipped during the execution? Or will it not be able to execute the script?

By 'wait-disabled', I mean a server which has disabled the use of the 'wait' command.

Answer (score 1):

It will allow the script execution and just ignore the command.